# Programación orientada a objetos Python

Tags: python, poo

tengo una duda referente a un programa que estoy intentando realizar. Estoy encallado en parte del registro de los socios a la plataforma, en dónde se pueden dar de alta, de baja o entrar simplemente para
disfrutar del contenido.
La cosa es que yo he realizado el siguiente código en la clase Gestion_socio que me permite dar de alta y/o de baja a un socio:

```
class Gestion_socios:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.socios = {} # Diccionario vacío con DNIs como keys
    
    def alta_socio(self):
        nombre_socio = input("Introduce tu nombre: ")
        dni = int(input("Introduce tu DNI sin letra: "))
        telefono = int(input("Introduce tu número de teléfono: "))
        datos_socio = {"Nombre":nombre_socio, "Teléfono":telefono}
        if dni not in self.socios:
            self.socios[dni] = datos_socio
        else: 
            print("Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado")
        
    def baja_socio(self,dni):
        if dni in self.socios:
            self.socios.pop(dni)
            print("Has sido borrado satisfactoriamente")
```

Pero mi duda es, si por ejemplo simplemente quiero que el socio entre a la plataforma, entiendo que me podrá ser útil en mi app hacer una clase tipo lo siguiente:

```
class Socio:
    
    def __init__(self,nombre_socio,dni,telefono): # Definimos el constructor de la clase Socio
        self.nombre = nombre_socio
        self.dni = dni
        self.telefono = telefono
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Nombre: {}\nDNI: {}\nTelefono: {}".format(self.nombre,self.dni,self.telefono)
```

Pero mi duda es cómo puedo realizar lo mismo que había realizado al principio en los métodos de alta_socio y baja_socio, pero teniendo en cuenta la class Socio?
Había pensado algo así, pero se que está mal:

```
class Gestion_socios(Socio):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.socios = {} # Diccionario vacío con DNIs como keys
    
    def alta_socio(self,nombre_socio,dni,telefono):
        if dni not in self.socios:
            self.socios[dni] = Socio(nombre_socio,dni,telefono)
        else: 
            print("Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado")
```

Comment: No creo que sea necesario que `Gestion_socios` herede de `Socio`.

Comment: Yo lo que me pregunto es si puedo realizar lo siguiente por ejemplo: self.socios[dni] = Socio(nombre_socio,dni,telefono), siendo socio la clase

Comment: Que pongas `self.socios[dni] = Socio(nombre_socio,dni,telefono)` no está mal, pero sí la herencia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ya que la pregunta es de OOP, haría mal con responder y no señalar las cosas que se pueden mejorar (desde mi humilde perspectiva). Empecemos...

Sí, definitivamente está mal heredar de una clase para sobreescribir un método al cual estás cambiando sus parámetros de entrada. Con esto estás rompiendo con el [Principio de Sustitución de Liskov](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_sustituci%C3%B3n_de_Liskov).

Ahora bien, hiciste bien en separar los *concerns* al crear una clase que gestione el registro, y otra que represente la entidad Socio. Sin embargo, la clase `Socio` parece ser más un [DTO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_transferencia_de_datos) que una clase propiamente dicha. Para esto, Python provee las maravillosas [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Así, puedes representar a la entidad Socio de la siguiente manera:

```
from collections import namedtuple


Socio = namedtuple('Socio', 'nombre dni telefono')
```

Ahora vamos con la parte de gestión de registros. Otro principio que hay que tener en cuenta a la hora de diseñar sistemas bajo el paradigma OO, es que cada clase debe tener una única responsabilidad ([SRP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica)). Por lo tanto estaríamos haciendo un error si la clase `Gestion_socios` se encarga de en efecto gestionar los registros y además de servir como interfaz al usuario.

¿Qué tal si abstraemos las tareas de gestión de socios y creamos una clase más genérica capaz de añadir y eliminar objetos de tu "base de datos"? Así podemos tener esta clase lista por si en algún momento deseas ya no solo agregar socios, sino empleados, visitantes, etc.

Además, vamos a aprovechar y desacoplamos nuestra "base de datos" de esa clase, y así cumplimos con el [Principio de inversión de la dependencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_inversi%C3%B3n_de_la_dependencia), dando la posibilidad de "inyectar" la base de datos de nuestro sistema a la clase encargada de manejarla (lo cual sería beneficioso si quieres cargar un diccionario ya existente).

Yo sugeriría que esa clase se pareciera a lo siguiente:

```
class GestorDePersonas:
    def __init__(self, database=None):
        if database is None:
            database = dict()
        self.database = database

    def add(self, objeto):
        if self._existe(objeto):
            raise KeyError(f'{objeto.__class__.__name__} ya existente')
        self.database[objeto.dni] = objeto

    def remove(self, objeto):
        if self._existe(objeto):
            self.database.pop(objeto.dni)
        else:
            raise KeyError(f'{objeto.__class__.__name__} no existe')

    def get(self, dni):
        sentinel = type('', (), {})
        sentinel.dni = None
        return self.database.get(dni, sentinel)

    def _existe(self, objeto):
        dni = objeto.dni
        return True if dni in self.database else False
```

Ahora, creemos una clase responsable de ser la interfaz entre el usuario y nuestra aplicación.

```
class SocioUI:
    def __init__(self, gestor):
        self.gestor = gestor

    def dar_de_alta(self):
        try:
            nombre = input("Introduce tu nombre: ")
            dni = int(input("Introduce tu DNI sin letra: "))
            telefono = int(input("Introduce tu número de teléfono: "))
            socio = Socio(nombre, dni, telefono)
            self.gestor.add(socio)
            print('Socio añadido con éxito!')
        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)

    def dar_de_baja(self):
        try:
            dni = input('Ingresa tu dni')
            socio = self.gestor.get(dni)
            self.gestor.remove(socio)
        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)
```

Y así, finalmente, podemos usar nuestro pequeño sistema como muestro a continuación:

```
gestor = GestorDePersonas()
ui = SocioUI(gestor)
ui.dar_de_alta()
```

De esta manera, eso que preguntas de "entrar simplemente para disfrutar del contenido" lo puedes conseguir añadiendo los métodos de ese contenido que deseas mostrar, a la clase `SocioUI` (siempre y cuando ese contenido esté bajo la misma responsabilidad que los métodos ya creados en la clase), o puedes crear nuevas clases de UI que se alineen con el contenido deseado, y agrupar todas esas clases similares dentro de otra que sea la principal, o *main*. De ser así, puedes estudiar cómo aplicar el patrón de [Chain of responsability](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadena_de_responsabilidad) para agrupar estas clases que puedes crear.

---

Nota, por favor, cómo deben ser nombradas las clases y métodos, tanto por [convención](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), como por semántica (intentar que al nombrar clases, estas sean sustantivos, y los métodos sean verbos o predicados).

También, nota como *por lo general* conviene [favorecer la composición sobre la herencia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). No es que la herencia sea mala, sino que hay que saber cuándo usarla y sus implicancias más allá del simple hecho de copiar el código de una clase a otra. Es decir, considerar cosas como el coupling, la rigidez creada, ["explosión de clases"](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#the-class-explosion-problem), etc.)

Comment: +1 está respuesta es simplemente magnífica

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Siento los errores garrafales.

Comment: Solo me ha surgido dos pequeñas dudas, el "_" delante del método existe es porque lo estás encapsulando? Y si es así, por qué lo haces? Y la otra no acabo de entender el método get de la clase GestorDePersonas, si me lo puedes explicar un poco, lo agradezco. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tranquilo, colega, que no hay nada que sentir. Te respondo: 1. El underscore de prefijo significa que es un método cuya única intención es ser usado como utilitario por la clase. O sea, no es un método que esté pensado para ser expuesto. Nota que no he dicho "privado" porque tal cosa no existe en Python -- aunque se pueda conseguir algo similar con el [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) usando dunders --

Comment: Ese método `get()` lo hice para (como su nombre sugiere) obtener un registro del diccionario. Tiene sentido usarlo antes de `remove()`, ya que este último espera recibir un objeto como argumento. La parte que puede confundir de `get()` es esa variable `sentinel`, pero no te preocupes, que no es nada loco: Sencillamente es un objeto que pueda ser usado como valor por defecto en caso que el diccionario no encuentre el DNI solicitado.